# The value is null

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to create a  do loop based on this data. It has around 39 rows

```
ID         startdate
1          2020-1-1
```

This is my code so far

```
Do {
  $row1 = 9
  $tb2 = @() 
   if ($ws3.cells.Item($row1, 11).Value() -eq $ws1.Cells.Item(6, 8).Value()){
    dt2 =@{
    VesselID = [int] $ws1.Cells.Item(6, 3).Value2
        CrewId = [System.String] $ws3.Cells.Item($row1, 3).Value2
        SignOnVessel_Date = [datetime]::FromOADate($ws3.Cells.Item($row1, 11).Value2)
    }
    $Input2 = New-Object System.Object -property $dt2
    $tb2 += $Input2
    $row1++
    }else {
    $row1++
    }
  }Until ($row1 -eq 39)
```

But when I run the script it says that the value for if function appear null. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the code sets row1 to 9 every iteration. Isn't this a endless loop?

Comment: the code you show is not functional. you are supposed to post _working code_ so that folks can determine what the problem is. lookee ... How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is of course no way to check if what you are collecting from the worksheet is correct, but this is mainly about the logic where you went wrong.

Then there is a typo `dt2 =@{` where you forgot the dollar sign `$` in front of the variable name.

If you want to do this using a `do {..} Until(..)` loop, you need to initialize the counter variable `$row1` **above** the loop.
Also, since you are resetting the `$tb2 = @()`  in every iteration to an empty array, you won't get any results.

Best practice is to not use an array and add elements to it with `+=` as it recreates the **entire** array every time at the cost of memory and performance.

Try this

```
$row1 = 9
$tb2 = Do {
    if ($ws3.cells.Item($row1, 11).Value() -eq $ws1.Cells.Item(6, 8).Value()) {
        # just output a PSObject here, it will be captured in variable $tb2
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            VesselID          = [int] $ws1.Cells.Item(6, 3).Value2
            CrewId            = [string] $ws3.Cells.Item($row1, 3).Value2
            SignOnVessel_Date = [datetime]::FromOADate($ws3.Cells.Item($row1, 11).Value2)
        }
    }
    # increment $row1 regardless if we have output an object or not
    $row1++
} Until ($row1 -eq 39)
```

Or probably more efficient here, use a `for ()` loop:

```
$tb2 = for ($row1 = 9; $row1 -lt 40; $row1++) {
    if ($ws3.cells.Item($row1, 11).Value() -eq $ws1.Cells.Item(6, 8).Value()) {
        # just output a PSObject here, it will be captured in variable $tb2
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            VesselID          = [int] $ws1.Cells.Item(6, 3).Value2
            CrewId            = [string] $ws3.Cells.Item($row1, 3).Value2
            SignOnVessel_Date = [datetime]::FromOADate($ws3.Cells.Item($row1, 11).Value2)
        }
    }
}
```